# deadlock issues + increased number of goroutines while working with channel

Tags: go

I am working on a simple http status check program with Go. The program went fine at first. Then I've introduced `channel` into it, it just doesn't stop. In other words, `WorkGroup.Done()` is not triggered.

how can I trigger `WorkGroup.Done()`?

```golang
// go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1AzXEAV9p4K
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

type urlState struct {
    url   string
    state bool
}

func checkLink(link string, c chan<- urlState) {
    _, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(link, `is not working`)
        c <- urlState{
            url:   link,
            state: false,
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(link, `is working`)
        c <- urlState{
            url:   link,
            state: true,
        }
    }
}

func Check(links []string) bool {
    result := true
    stats := make(map[string]bool)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fmt.Println(`total sites: `, len(links))
    wg.Add(len(links)) // add workgroups of exactly same amount as links array length

    c := make(chan urlState, len(links))
    for _, link := range links {
        stats[link] = false
        fmt.Println(`requesting...`, link)
        go checkLink(link, c)
        fmt.Println(`goroutines: `, runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }

    for v := range c {
        fmt.Println(`recv from channel, assigning result for `, v.url)
        stats[v.url] = v.state
        wg.Done()
        fmt.Println(`goroutines: `, runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }

    wg.Wait() // any codes below are not reached. increased number of goroutines seem to be the reason. 
    close(c)
    fmt.Println(`work finished!`)
    for key, value := range stats {
        fmt.Println(key, `---`, value)
        if value == false {
            result = false
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
  links := []string{`https://goolgle.com`, `https://amazon.com`} // two goroutines are expected
  Check(links) // shows increased number of goroutines. and it goes deadlock
}
```

Comment: How many `links` are you processing?  I don't see any reason that it would never complete, but you've effectively told it to process _all_ links simultaneously. With a sufficiently large number of links, that would effectively be a fork bomb, and you'd consume so much memory just starting the goroutines, that it may effectively never finish. With sufficient RAM and time, it _should_ finish, logically.

Comment: What you probably need is a limit of, say, 10, or 50, or 100, links at a time.

Comment: @Flimzy that is a valid point. I've come across the similar case when I worked on web crawlers in different programming languages. However, I've written this code to get accustomed with Go. The code still doesn't finish even with just one link.

Comment: GoPlayground: https://play.golang.org/p/1AzXEAV9p4K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program blocks on `for v := range c` because range on a channel continues until the channel is closed.  Fix by receiving the expected number of values. The WaitGroup is not needed with this change.

```
result := true
stats := make(map[string]bool)
fmt.Println(`total sites: `, len(links))

c := make(chan urlState, len(links))
for _, link := range links {
    stats[link] = false
    fmt.Println(`requesting...`, link)
    go checkLink(link, c)
    fmt.Println(`goroutines: `, runtime.NumGoroutine())
}

for i := 0; i < len(links); i++ {
    v := <-c
    fmt.Println(`recv from channel, assigning result for `, v.url)
    stats[v.url] = v.state
    fmt.Println(`goroutines: `, runtime.NumGoroutine())
}

fmt.Println(`work finished!`)
for key, value := range stats {
    fmt.Println(key, `---`, value)
    if value == false {
        result = false
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k8wGD06BgEr)

A different way to fix the problem  is to close `c` after `checkLink` goroutines are complete. Use the WaitGroup to coordinate this.

```
func checkLink(link string, c chan<- urlState, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ... remainder of function is same as before
}

func Check(links []string) bool {
    result := true
    stats := make(map[string]bool)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fmt.Println(`total sites: `, len(links))
    wg.Add(len(links)) // add workgroups of exactly same amount as links array length

    c := make(chan urlState, len(links))
    for _, link := range links {
        stats[link] = false
        fmt.Println(`requesting...`, link)
        go checkLink(link, c, &wg)
        fmt.Println(`goroutines: `, runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }

    // Close c when checkLink goroutines complete.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    for v := range c {
        fmt.Println(`recv from channel, assigning result for `, v.url)
        stats[v.url] = v.state
        wg.Done()
        fmt.Println(`goroutines: `, runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }

    fmt.Println(`work finished!`)
    for key, value := range stats {
        fmt.Println(key, `---`, value)
        if value == false {
            result = false
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6qLMuC6OYwL)